# ObjectInputStream[] using the method readObject() freezing the program

Tags: java, stream, freeze, objectinputstream

I'm quite new to java programming and tried doing a simple program where I have a server and 2 other users that can communicate by sending simple message (string). Everything works, but I have a problem when I use the readObject method. Basically, if the second user write a message before the first user, that message will not appear on the server screen until the first user send a message. It seems that the method readObject will freeze the program until it actually receives and object from that user, and will then continue :

```
while (true) {
    message = (String) input[0].readObject();
    showMessage(message);
    message = (String) input[1].readObject();
    showMessage(message);
}
```

My question is : is there a way to let the second user send an object before the first one if he's the first one to send something? Do I have to create a separate thread for each user? Thank you!

Comment: I think you should use threads, one for listening to incoming data, and another for sending the data out, so that none of the two will block the other

Comment: @BackSlash That won't fix it. He needs to use a thread *per connection*.